# How can I check model's data is connected accurately?

Tags: python, django

I wanna check whether model's data is connected accurately or not.
models.py is

```
class User(models.Model):
    trunsaction_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    regist_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    user_id = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
    age = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
    area = models.ForeignKey('Area',null=True, blank=True)

class Area(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='Area', null=True)

class Prefecture(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='Prefecture')
    area = models.ForeignKey('Area', null=True, blank=True)

class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='City')
    prefecture = models.ForeignKey('Prefecture', null=True, blank=True)

class Price(models.Model):
    upper1000 = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='u1000', null=True)
    from500to1000 = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='500～1000', null=True)
    under500 = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='d500', null=True)
    city = models.ForeignKey('City', null=True, blank=True)
```

Model's data means Area&Prefecture&City&Price,so I wanna know these data is connected accurately with User.How can I check this?I cannot find it to see db.sqlite3 by using DB Browser for SQLite .How can I print the answer in terminal?

Comment: What exactly are you asking here? Why wouldn't the data be "connected accurately"? What reason do you have to think that it is not? And why can't you use the sqlite browser, if that's what you want to do?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I wanna see these model's data linking in terminal.The reason of not being able to see in  the sqlite browser is that I cannot understand how all data is put in db.So I wanna see all data connecting in terminal.

Answer (score 2):

The database functionality in Django is well tested and I see no reason that this should not work like you expect.

However, unit tests might help you to verify that you models are indeed correct. You could structure minimal, isolated unit tests that attempts to create, save and fetch your models, and validate that the structure is intact throughout the operations.

For example, a minimal test suit inspired by the [Django documentation:](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/testing/overview/#writing-tests)

```
from django.test import TestCase
from myapp.models import User

class UserTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        area = Area.objects.create(name='foobar')
        User.objects.create(user_id="foo", area=area)

    def test_user_has_area_reference(self):
        user = User.objects.get(user_id="foo")
        self.assertEquals(user.area.name, 'foobar')
```